# Closing socket when stopping Nifi costom processor

Tags: java, sockets, apache-nifi

I've been working at a custom NiFi processor (extends AbstractProcessor) that is pretty much supposed to do the same as PutTCP but customized for my own server. It receives a flowfile and sends the data content to the server through a socket. using:

```
import java.net.Socket;

newSocket = new Socket(serverName, port)
newSocketOut = newSocket.getOutputStream();
newSocketReader = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(newSocket.getInputStream()));
```

The problem is that when I stop the processor it never triggers onUnScheduled() or onStopped() which leaves the sockets unclosed since that is where I was supposed to close them. I do have onScheduled() which works fine. Any ideas on how to get my sockets to close when I stop the processor or why onUnscheduled() or onStopped() never triggers?

Comment: Can you share the code for your processor?  Any method annotated with OnUnscheduled or OnStopped should be called when you stop the processor, so there has to be something going on in your processor

Comment: Here is how PutTCP closes its connections... https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-extension-utils/nifi-processor-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/util/put/AbstractPutEventProcessor.java#L222